# jquery map dynamically create cells

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I'm working on a basic map that is organized in the standard X/Y coordinate fashion. At each coordinate (x,y), there are contents that are stored in the database (the contents for each location is loaded via php/mysql database).

At my current setup, the map is just placed in the page as a static object, and I've used jquery/ajax to update the display and data for the coordinates.

I'm looking for a way to have a dynamically loaded click & Drag map, that will load cells as they are needed. (what ever comes into your view--in this case the window, should be loaded from the server--a div be created with the proper coordinates relative to its surrounding cells).

As of right now, my static map has this setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeVYO.gif  (link because i cannot post pics)

The images are placed row by row (z index changing as each row goes down to give the appearance of overlap).
If that same pattern were to be duplicated, to dynamically create those cells, you can see that when a row sticks out on the right side, there is room on the left side, leaving easy overlapping.

I haven't been able to find any way to accomplish this:
1) When a cell (region with multiple coordinates inside) is visible, check to see if the surrounding 8 cells are already loaded.
2) If a surrounding 1 of 8 cells are not loaded, create the cell in the correct position, and assign the 'center coord' so that the generated data has a reference point.
3) Ensure that the cells are movable via click&drag, as well as the ability to click on the objects under (to interact).
4) Cells cannot be accessed by scrolling (scroll bar)

I have a feeling its fairly complicated, but I'm looking for the best way to do it, so ANY help or direction would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering, and lots of google searching, a quick search for "jquery infinite drag" returned this result:
http://ianli.com/infinitedrag/

I managed to use the function call provided when each cell is created, to gather map data from the database (ajax) and create the cells as needed.
http://mc1.empirebattles.com/map/jquery_map.html

I REALLY like the way its working so far, except that if i want to be able to click on anything under the map (for actions and such), the click event is called whenever i release the click for dragging the map around.... i've tried jquery's UI doubleclick, but it appears this plugin takes control as soon as double click is called

Anyways, incase anyone else needs something similar to this, this solution has helped me lots!

Answer (score 0):

With all my desire to help, I really cannot give the answer that will solve the problem, which I apologize for, but I think I can try to direct you to something.

It's the HTML 5's canvas and relative functions.

Look at that:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Maybe also you have to look at how a MAP is built with HTML 5

Comment: I'd looked at the html5 canvas' before, as well as the kinetic ability to drag the stage (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-the-stage-with-kineticjs/). The issues i'm getting there, is 1: the ability to 'grab' each object externally (such as using javascript/jquery), to either get the contents info, or change the contents of each object, and 2: dynamically creating based off of the surroundings.
There may be more issues that i cant see, but i didn't get TOO deep into it, seeing as i couldn't get the basic functionality i was looking for.